# How to Remove a section of text from a string using powershell?

Tags: powershell

I a building an email and have this section of content in that email which I need to remove at times so I am tying to do a replace from #HOUSESTART through #HOUSEEND using the -replace but it is not working.

$body contains this section along with much more of the entire html email:

```
"<p class=MsoNormal style='margin-bottom:0in;margin-bottom:.0001pt;line-height:
    normal'><b><u><span style='mso-ascii-font-family:Calibri;mso-fareast-font-family:
    "Times New Roman";mso-hansi-font-family:Calibri;mso-bidi-font-family:Calibri'>#HOUSESTART<o:p></o:p></span></u></b></p>

    <p class=MsoNormal style='margin-bottom:0in;margin-bottom:.0001pt;line-height:
    normal'><b><u><span style='mso-ascii-font-family:Calibri;mso-fareast-font-family:
    "Times New Roman";mso-hansi-font-family:Calibri;mso-bidi-font-family:Calibri'>PLEASE
    NOTE</span></u></b><span style='mso-ascii-font-family:Calibri;mso-fareast-font-family:
    "Times New Roman";mso-hansi-font-family:Calibri;mso-bidi-font-family:Calibri'>:&nbsp;
    As a house manager, you have two email addresses.&nbsp; Your secondary email
    address is #EMAIL.&nbsp; The only place you will need to use this email address
    is when you are enrolling any device in the Targeted Threat Protection.<span
    style='mso-spacerun:yes'>  </span><b><span style='background:yellow;mso-highlight:
    yellow'>(Only used in manager welcome emails.)</span><o:p></o:p></b></span></p>

    <p class=MsoNormal style='margin-bottom:0in;margin-bottom:.0001pt;line-height:
    normal'><b><span style='mso-ascii-font-family:Calibri;mso-fareast-font-family:
    "Times New Roman";mso-hansi-font-family:Calibri;mso-bidi-font-family:Calibri'>#HOUSEEND</span></b><span
    style='mso-ascii-font-family:Calibri;mso-fareast-font-family:"Times New Roman";
    mso-hansi-font-family:Calibri;mso-bidi-font-family:Calibri'><o:p></o:p></span></p>
```

I am using this command to try and remove everything between #HOUSESTART and #HOUSEEND but it is not removing it.

```
$body = $body -replace "#HOUSESTART.*#HOUSEEND"," "
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: if you make that into a single multiline string, then this >>> `-replace '(?ms)#HouseStart.+#HouseEnd' <<< will do the job. i am not able to make it work with an array of single-line strings. [*blush*]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default, metacharacter `.` in .NET regexes matches any character *except newlines*.

Therefore, **if you want `.*` to match *across multiple lines***, i.e, to match newlines too, you must **use inline [regex option](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/regular-expression-options) `s` (`(?s)`** at the very start of the regex):

```
$body = $body -replace '(?s)#HOUSESTART.*#HOUSEEND', ' '
```

<sup>Note:

* I'm using `'...'` (single quotes, i.e. verbatim strings) rather than `"..."` (expandable (interpolating) string), to avoid confusion between what PowerShell may interpret *up front*, and what the regex engine will see.

* `.*` matches *greedily*, so that everything to the input's *last* instance of `#HOUSEEND` is matched; if there can be multiple instances, and you want to match only through the *next* one, use the *non-greedy* `.*?`</sup>

Note that `$body` must be a *single, multi-line* string for this to work.

For instance, if you use something like `$body = Get-Content file.txt` to set `$body`, you'll end up with an *array* of strings, *each of which* the `-replace` operation is applied to, which won't work. In that case, use the `-Raw` switch to ensure that the file is read as a single, multi-line string: 
`$body = Get-Content -Raw file.txt`.

Comment: Glad to hear it, @ToddWelch.